# Multiple middlewares do not work as wanted

Tags: laravel, routes, middleware, laravel-5.6, laravel-middleware

If I have 3 user roles (head, admin and moderator):

I want to allow head to all methods, admin to most methods and moderator to one method.

Inside InstitutionsController:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('head');
    $this->middleware('admin')->only(['index', 'create']);
    $this->middleware('moderator')->only(['index']);
}
```

By this I cannot open visit index method as moderator or admin, just as head...

How can I achieve this?

BTW my middlewares have: `return !auth()->user()->isAdmin()?redirect()->home():$next($request)` etc for other 2

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware). They are classes that manipulate HTTP requests and responses. A request comes in, a response comes out. They’re processed one at a time. So if you have a middleware that checks a role, it’s going to check that role and throw an “Unauthorized” response if the user does not have that role.

As such, checking if a user can do something is not the job of middleware (as you have found). If you want to check a user can do something, use a [policy](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization#creating-policies) around your resource instead.

The [Authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization) documentation has more information on creating policies and authorizing actions in your Laravel applications.

Comment: Can you give me some example? I am understanding what is for but I am not how does it know that when I visit route with lets say homecontroller and method index it needs to run homepolicy with before method to check is user admin or not.

Comment: @StupidKid The documentation explains all: https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization#via-controller-helpers